# Making a list based on another list (sharepoint)

Tags: list, sharepoint

I have imported a table from access, which is a list of books.. Now I need to make a new table, that has all of these items (books) in it, but I can't seem to figure out how I can get the items from the imported list to the new list.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by creating a list template and checking a checkbox that says: *Include Contents* and then create a new list based on this template.

Step by step instructions available on [MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-a-list-by-using-a-list-template-HA101782479.aspx):

### STEP 1: Create a list template

*SECURITY   This step does not save any security settings that may have been applied to the list. Save this list template to a secure place so that it cannot be restored by someone who should not have access to this content.*

1. Navigate to the site containing the list for which you want to create a list template.
2. In the ribbon, click the List tab, and then in the Settings section, click List Settings.
3. In the Permissions and Management column, click Save list as template.

   The Save as Template page appears.
4. In the File Name box, type the file name to use for the template file.

   *NOTE    Do not add a file extension to the file name. The .stp file extension is automatically added for you.*
5. In the Template name box, type the title that you want to appear in the list template gallery for this template.
6. In the Template Description box, type a description for the template.
7. Do one of the following:

   - To copy just the list definition, clear the Include Content check box.
   - To copy the list definition and all the data in the list, select the Include Content check box.
8. Click OK.

The new list template is now available from the list template gallery.

### Step 2: Create a new list based on the list template.

1. Navigate to the site where you want to create the list.
2. Click Site Actions Site Actions Menu, click View All Site Content, and then click Create Create Button.

   *NOTE    A site can be significantly modified in appearance and navigation. If you cannot locate an option, such as a command, button, or link, contact your administrator.*
3. Under Lists, select the list template created in Step 1: Create a list template.
4. Type the Name for the list. Name is required.

   The name appears at the top of the list in most views, becomes part of the Web address for the list page, and appears in site navigation to help users to find the list. You can change the name of a list, but the Web address will remain the same.
5. Type the Description for the list. Description is optional.

   The description appears below the name in most views. Some types of lists can receive content by e-mail. If you plan to enable the list to receive content by e-mail, you can add the e-mail address of the list to its description, so that people can easily find the e-mail address. You can change the description for a list.
6. To add a link to this list on the Quick Launch, verify that Yes is selected in the Navigation section.
7. If there is an E-mail section, your administrator has enabled lists on your site to receive content by e-mail. To enable people to add content to this list by sending e-mail, click Yes under Enable this list to receive e-mail. Then, in the Email address box, type the first part of the address that you want people to use for the list. This option is not available for all types of list.
8. Click Create.

   *NOTE    By default, you can create a list template that contains up to 10 megabytes (MB) of content. However, an administrator can increase this size limit.*

For copying list template to other site collection, see provided MSDN URL on top.